# Zend Freamwork 2 Album module

Tags: zend-framework

I am using windows 7 . I use Xampp to access the zend module such as: http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/public/

I created Album module form zend official web site.
But when I try to open http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/public/album link 
,I get the following error. 
[image]
Please Help

Comment: did you create the AlbumTable?

Comment: yes! From php my admin

Comment: okay, did you do this? http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Comment: Oh! zajak Allah hu khair. I found the mistake.  I was not edit global.php correctely. My module is now working.